# Dynamically Create Kendo Drop Down Lists from Array of Arrays

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a list of Arrays from a web service stored in a variable.

If I use one array, or a list of 1 objects it works.

If I use a List of any number longer than 1 array, only the last generated drop down list will work. The data appears lost, as I can't click the control and see items.

Inspecting the object in the console doesn't show data.

The Javascript / Jquery function looks like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filters.data.length; i++) {
            var control = $scope.filters.data[i];

            var optionName = control.Name
            if (control.UiType == "SingleSelect") {
                var controlName = "selectFilterFor" + optionName.trim();

                var selectControl = $scope.getSingleSelect(optionName, controlName);

                $(".search-panel-fields")[0].innerHTML += selectControl;

                var selectorName = "#" + controlName;

                //$(controlName).kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");

                $(selectorName).kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "Value",
                    dataSource: control.Attributes,
                    dataBound: onDataBound,
                    //index: 0,
                    optionLabel: { Name: "", Value: "" }
                });

            }

        }
```

I thought the DOM might be too slow, but adding a setTimeout(function() {//updateDom }, 1000); had no effect.

I also added some logging on a dataBound event to see if it all looks good:

```
dataBound: function (e) {
     console.log('data is bound: ' + control.Name);
     console.log(e.sender.dataItems());
  },
```

And the element, with an array of data is there. I specifically am avoiding an additional network call right now.

A quick, modified version of the JSON Data:

```
{"JSON":[{"SHORT":"AREA","Name":"Areas","UIOGLItrol":{"Name":"Area","UiType":"SingleSelect"},"Attributes":[{"Name":"BuildWEZL Area A","Value":"A","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"9611","Value":"9611","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true}]},{"SHORT":"HAVOCSAYOR","Name":"HAVOCSAYORs","UIOGLItrol":{"Name":"HAVOCSAYOR","UiType":"SingleSelect"},"Attributes":[{"Name":"NO HAVOCSAYOR","Value":"ND","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"BUILDWEZL","Value":"BLD","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"MARIL","Value":"MAR","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"SAMMARAL","Value":"ELE","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"GENERAL","Value":"GEN","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"GUILDMENTATION","Value":"INS","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"PARTS","Value":"MECH","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"MANA DELIVERY","Value":"PDL","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"PROJECT MANAGEMENT","Value":"PMGT","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"MEGAUTIL","Value":"STR","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"OGLISTTERMION","Value":"OGLI","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"PIPWEZL","Value":"PIP","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"ANTLERS","Value":"QC","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true}]},{"SHORT":"ItemISION","Name":"Itemisions","UIOGLItrol":{"Name":"Itemision","UiType":"SingleSelect"},"Attributes":[{"Name":"Item - (Placeholder)","Value":"-","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item A","Value":"A","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item B","Value":"B","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item C","Value":"C","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item D","Value":"D","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item E","Value":"E","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item F","Value":"F","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item G","Value":"G","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item H","Value":"H","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item J","Value":"J","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item K","Value":"K","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 00","Value":"00","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 01","Value":"01","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 02","Value":"02","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 03","Value":"03","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 04","Value":"04","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 05","Value":"05","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 06","Value":"06","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 07","Value":"07","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 08","Value":"08","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 09","Value":"09","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 10","Value":"10","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item I","Value":"I","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true},{"Name":"Item 11","Value":"11","FieldType":null,"IsActive":true}]}],"Response Payload":{"EDITOR_OGLIFIG":{"text":"[{\"SHORT\":\"AREA\",\"Name\":\"Areas\",\"UIOGLItrol\":{\"Name\":\"Area\",\"UiType\":\"SWEZLleSelect\"},\"Attributes\":[{\"Name\":\"BuildWEZL Area A\",\"Value\":\"A\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"9611\",\"Value\":\"9611\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true}]},{\"SHORT\":\"HAVOCSAYOR\",\"Name\":\"HAVOCSAYORs\",\"UIOGLItrol\":{\"Name\":\"HAVOCSAYOR\",\"UiType\":\"SWEZLleSelect\"},\"Attributes\":[{\"Name\":\"NO HAVOCSAYOR\",\"Value\":\"ND\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"BUILDWEZL\",\"Value\":\"BLD\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"MARIL\",\"Value\":\"MAR\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"SAMMARAL\",\"Value\":\"ELE\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"GENERAL\",\"Value\":\"GEN\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"GUILDMENTATION\",\"Value\":\"INS\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"PARTS\",\"Value\":\"MECH\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"MANA DELIVERY\",\"Value\":\"PDL\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"PROJECT MANAGEMENT\",\"Value\":\"PMGT\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"MEGAUTIL\",\"Value\":\"STR\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"OGLISTTERMION\",\"Value\":\"OGLI\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"PIPWEZL\",\"Value\":\"PIP\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"ANTLERS\",\"Value\":\"QC\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true}]},{\"SHORT\":\"ItemISION\",\"Name\":\"Itemisions\",\"UIOGLItrol\":{\"Name\":\"Itemision\",\"UiType\":\"SWEZLleSelect\"},\"Attributes\":[{\"Name\":\"Item - (Placeholder)\",\"Value\":\"-\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item A\",\"Value\":\"A\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item B\",\"Value\":\"B\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item C\",\"Value\":\"C\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item D\",\"Value\":\"D\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item E\",\"Value\":\"E\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item F\",\"Value\":\"F\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item G\",\"Value\":\"G\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item H\",\"Value\":\"H\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item J\",\"Value\":\"J\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item K\",\"Value\":\"K\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 00\",\"Value\":\"00\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 01\",\"Value\":\"01\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 02\",\"Value\":\"02\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 03\",\"Value\":\"03\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 04\",\"Value\":\"04\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 05\",\"Value\":\"05\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 06\",\"Value\":\"06\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 07\",\"Value\":\"07\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 08\",\"Value\":\"08\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 09\",\"Value\":\"09\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 10\",\"Value\":\"10\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item I\",\"Value\":\"I\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true},{\"Name\":\"Item 11\",\"Value\":\"11\",\"FieldType\":null,\"IsActive\":true}]}]","mode":"application/json"}}}
```

How do I get Kendo to instantiate all of the objects correctly?

Comment: is this the kind of thing you are after? https://dojo.telerik.com/OdeXiGUn

Comment: @DavidShorthose yes, and at a glance the important bits there are identical enough... So that adds to the confusion!

Comment: can you provide a sample of the array you are binding

Comment: @DavidShorthose, it's long, obfuscated just in case, and there now.

Comment: ok here is a more expanded example. Hopefully you can see what is going off. If this works for you I will add a more complete answer for you https://dojo.telerik.com/OdeXiGUn/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be having some problems with the properties of the items in the array.
A safer approach for adding elements would be `.appendTo` instead of `innerHTML` concatenation

Based on the 'modified data' shown in the question, the following should construct three kendo drop downs.

```
  response.JSON.forEach (control => 
  { if (control.UIOGLItrol.UiType == "SingleSelect") 
    {
      var controlId = "selectFilterFor" + control.Name;

      $("<input>", {id:controlId, name:control.Name, class:"ssInput", type:"text"})
      .appendTo(".search-panel-fields");

      $("#"+controlId).kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        dataSource: control.Attributes,
        dataBound: onDataBound,
        optionLabel: { Name:"", Value:"" }
      });
    }
  });
```

See this [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@RichardAD/EDaDIMOF/4)

Comment: Perfect. Who would have expected Jquery's AppendTo would behave so differently. I'd live a link with explanation to why either this is better, or why looping through Javascripts append doesn't work as expected.

Comment: From docs "The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted into the target container."  **For `innerHTML +=` you might've added the HTML of the control itself (`+=selectControl.outerHTML`)**